# How to verify one java framework deployed in Tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have one Java web app deployed in Tomcat 7 and I've got exception as below:

```
Sep 29, 2015 1:36:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [arms-api] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objenesis/Objenesis] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objenesis.Objenesis
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at ch.lambdaj.proxy.ProxyUtil.createProxy(ProxyUtil.java:52)
    at ch.lambdaj.proxy.ProxyUtil.createIterableProxy(ProxyUtil.java:76)
    at ch.lambdaj.function.aggregate.ProxyAggregator.createProxyAggregator(ProxyAggregator.java:49)
    at ch.lambdaj.Lambda.aggregateFrom(Lambda.java:573)
    at ch.lambdaj.Lambda.aggregateFrom(Lambda.java:556)
    at ch.lambdaj.Lambda.joinFrom(Lambda.java:902)
```

My code is calling joinFrom from lambdaj-2.4.jar. Looks like the jar is not in the classpath.

But I checked the tomcat and the jar is under /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib folder. 
I tried setup JMX to monitoring this tomcat server. So, is there any way I can confirm this jar been loaded in Server? I searched in MBenas, but no luck.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a maven or some other solution for dependency management? If no, you should try to use it, because in your case, lambdaj library has it's own dependencies. Take a look at [maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.lambdaj/lambdaj/2.3.3), for example. It depends on the Objenesis library and some more libs. You have to provide them too, if you want to use LambdaJ. And the class, wich was not found, is from Objenesis library.

**Update:**
You can use some not server specific tools to get all loaded by JVM classes, for example [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html):

```
jmap -histo <PID>
```

To get a list of all loaded classes or you can try to use a jvisualvm.

Comment: It's old application which is suing ANT as build tool. Issue is the build package is fine and working in DEV and PROD, but UAT. might be the OS patch issue or others. So my concern is how to verify the dependencies are loaded in tomcat Server.

Comment: Hm, strange behaviour. Updated an answer, you can list the classes loaded by jvm, no need to take care of tomcat, it's just all jvm specific anyway